# Custom UI for notifications in node-webkit

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I am trying to develop a web app using node webkit. Whenever I receive any notification, I currently display it to the user by using Windows system tray notification. However currently it uses the current theme of Windows notification popup.

Is there a way to create a custom UI to do the same? (Like the pop up which comes when a user comes online on Skype). Is it possible to do using node webkit?

Comment: no, notifications always look like the OS/browser wants them to, not like you want them to

Comment: you can check out html5 notification.
https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/e/l/elfoxero/c17223c414d8ddafb7808972b5617d9e/html5-notifications_1400214081_demo_package/index.html and 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification